# while creating coreML model i have the error..."Unable to open output backtrace file."

Tags: image, classification, coreml, createml, createmlui

I am creating a Coreml image classifier, during training i get an error saying that "Unable to open output backtrace file.". I have a sneaking suspicion that this is due to the large amount of files...anyone else had this issue?

Comment: I haven't had the issue but I've only trained on Create ML with relatively small amounts of files. How many files are you using?

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans I’m using around 50000 files in 100 different classes

Comment: That's big but not super big. Have you tried just training on 2 classes?

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans do you think it could have something to do with the amount of ram it uses? If I train on less classes it’s fine.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans I have tried training with less classes and it’s successful 50% of the time. Maybe a ram issue?

Comment: Perhaps. How much RAM do you have?

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans 16GB MacBook Pro

Comment: That seems like it would have enough RAM to train a classifier but perhaps there is a bug in Create ML?